# Does AtomicBoolean guarantee "safe-thread"?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic

According to some documents I have read in the Internet, the variables of class Atomic like `AtomicInteger`, `AtomicLong`,... only allow 1 thread to access to them at the same time. But when I tried testing with `AtomicBoolean`, something went wrong. For example

```
public class TestAtomicBoolean {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final AtomicBoolean atomicBoolean = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        new Thread("T1") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is waiting for T3 set Atomic to true. Current is " + atomicBoolean.get());
                    if (atomicBoolean.compareAndSet(true, false)) {                        
                        System.out.println("Done. Atomic now is " + atomicBoolean.get());
                        break;
                    }                    
                }
            }
        }.start();

        new Thread("T2") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + atomicBoolean.get());                    
                }               
            }           
        }.start();

        new Thread("T3") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + atomicBoolean.get());
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is setting atomic to true");
                atomicBoolean.set(true);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + atomicBoolean.get());
            }           
        }.start();                
    }
}
```

Output

```
T1 is waiting for T3 set Atomic to true. Current is false
T1 is waiting for T3 set Atomic to true. Current is false
T3 is setting atomic to true
T2 false
T3 true (*)
T1 is waiting for T3 set Atomic to true. Current is false (*)
T2 true
Done. Atomic now is false
T2 false
```

At 2 line (*), although T3 set `AtomicBoolean` to true, after that, T1 read the value was false. So, T1 and T3 access the `AtomicBoolean` at the same time? I can't understand how `AtomicBoolean` works.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Can you explain more clearly? :(

Comment: There is no magic bullet that will guarantee thread safety.  Even if every operation performed by your code is individually thread-safe, that will not necessarily make the whole thing thread-safe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AtomicBoolean` is definitely atomic and thread-safe.

But in your example you are trying to test this atomic nature of AtomicBoolean relying on order the `System.out.println` prints the logs which is misleading.

So if we look at the `System.out.println()` code:

```
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

We will see the flow of events with the above `println()` method in context.

**Short Answer**

Thread T1 prints -> is waiting for T3 set Atomic to true. Current is false
Thread T1 prints -> is waiting for T3 set Atomic to true. Current is false
Thread T3 prints -> T3 is setting atomic to true
Thread T1 **calls sysout** to print -> is waiting for T3 set Atomic to true. Current is false (Just called the **sysout method but lock not yet acquired**)
Thread T3 prints ->printing of T3 true
Thread T1 **sysout complete** and prints -> is waiting for T3 set Atomic to true. Current is false

The order of the logs gives an impression that T1 has not read the current value of atomicBoolean, whereas it is because of the interleaving of threads that can happened while doing a `System.out.println`.

**Detailed sequence**

Application starts with initial value of `false` for `atomicBoolean`

```
final AtomicBoolean atomicBoolean = new AtomicBoolean(false);
```

The initial two logs from your output are from T1 as expected and it prints the value of `atomicBoolean` as `false`. For now we will ignore T2 to simplify as we can see the flow even with two threads.

Now T3 starts executing and is about to make `atomicBoolean` to `true` as indicated in the ouput.

```
T3 is setting atomic to true
```

And immediately after printing the above line, T1 gets a chance to execute. At this point the value of `atomicBoolean` is `false`. So JVM creates the string `T1 is waiting for T3 set Atomic to true. Current is false` and about the call or just entered the `System.out.println` method but not yet reached the `synchronized(this)` statement and so no lock is obtained yet on `this`.

At this point it could happen the T3 has got its turn to continue execution and makes the `atomicBoolean` to `true` and also prints the line `T3 true` using `System.out.println()` i.e., acquires and releases the lock (on `this`).

Now T1 resumes execution from where it left last time i.e.,  `System.out.println`. But remember the value of String it is trying to print was already built and its value is `T1 is waiting for T3 set Atomic to true. Current is false`. So now T1 prints this line and continues.

Effectively with this flow the logs would be as you observed.

```
T3 true
T1 is waiting for T3 set Atomic to true. Current is false
```

**Pictorial representation**

Below is the flow w.r.t T1 & T3 and (tries to) captures the above discussion. `----` indicates that thread is currently executing. Spaces indicates it is waiting for its turn.

```
    1(false) 1(false)           1(false)just invoked   1(false)completed
T1 -------------------          ------                ------------------
T3                    ----------      ----------------  
                       2(false)        3(true)

LEGEND:
 1(false) - printing of T1 is waiting for T3 set Atomic to true. Current is false
 2(false) - printing of T3 is setting atomic to true
 3(true) - printing of T3 true
```

Comment: Use a logging framework log4j for multithreading http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/

Comment: @mubeen Frankly, not cent percent sure if such logging already exists or can be achieved in our code. One option I can think of is writing a utility class and have `static synchronized` method that internally calls `sysout()`. But I do feel and can almost see there is still small window where the above flow can occur.

Comment: I got it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than referring to "some documents", you might want to try reading the official docs at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html

A quick and easy way to think about the classes in the atomic package is that each method such as get, set, compareAndSet behaves as if it was synchronized (forgetting the lazy and weak methods).

Comment: I have read this official docs, but I still don't understand :( "AtomicBoolean: A boolean value that may be updated atomically." In my example, it isn't "atomic" :s 2 threads can access to it at the same time :s